# COA to change SSID

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

Can COA be used to change SSID of a device. I am trying to set up packet fence as  captive portal solution. Here is what I found in documentation

> On wireless networks, the usual PacketFence setup dictate that you configure two SSIDs: an open one and a secure one. The open one is used to help users configure the secure one properly and requires authentication over the captive portal.

I am trying to understand how COA can change SSID on the device

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't.

CoA can change attributes of an existing connection (disconnect a user, apply different policy etc.), but SSID selection is a function of the wireless client (think Layer 1), not the authentication process (Layer 2).

If you think about it from a Wired network perspective, that would be like trying to use CoA to patch a user into another port.